# Knowing $c(x)=\int_0^x e^t\, \cos f(t) dt$ calculate $s(x)=\int_0^x e^t\, \sin f(t) dt.$

Tags: calculus, integration

Knowing the function $c(x)$ defined as
$$c(x)=\int_0^x e^t\, \cos f(t) dt$$
is it possible to find
$$s(x)=\int_0^x e^t\, \sin f(t) dt,$$
for $f\in C^1(\mathbb R)$?

For example, if $f(t)=t$, we have
$$c(x)=\frac{1}{2}\left(-1+e^x\left(\cos x+\sin x\right)\right), \ \ s(x)=\frac{1}{2}\left(1+e^x\left(-\cos x+\sin x\right)\right).$$
Then: 
$$s(x)=-c(x)-e^x \sin x.$$
What we can say for a generic function $f(t)$?

Comment: For a **general** function $f(t)$ we cannot say anything, since I think that the integral could also not be simple/possible to find. For example, if $f(t) = t^t$.....

Comment: As Helium said. Please provide some restrictions on your function $f(t)$, when your question might have a better chance to be answered. One of the problems is your limit $0$. What if $f(t)=1/t$?